# How to recover data on a Mac Pro OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, restore

I will probably have to replace my hard drive. I have a disk that will restore files (from a previous HD replacement), but the technicians didn't supply me with the serial number, so I can't use it.

Is there free software for my computer so I can restore my personal files?

Comment: Would I be able to retrieve the serial number from my existing file restoring disk?

Comment: By the way, you can edit a question to add things such as that last comment. Also, what exactly is your question, is your backup disk a Time machine backup? Also, why do you need the serial number?

Comment: @CarolRose Part of being on StackExchange also means coming back and either answering clarifying comments, or leaving other comments so we know if what we have so far suggested has worked for you. Please allow us to help the rest of the community by giving some more feedback

Answer (score 0):

OSX does not require a serial number, unless you're installing the Server version, which should be on the package. If you can find the original disks that came with your Mac, you should be able to restore from those disks, but the data from your previous HDD will need to be copied back later